# $f_n \to f$ a.e. and $\lvert f_n(x) \rvert \le \lvert f(x) \rvert $ where $f_n, f \in L^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

If we have $f_n \to f$ a.e. and $\lvert f_n(x) \rvert \le \lvert f(x) \rvert $ a.e. where $f_n, f \in L^\infty$

Does this give enough to ensure $\lvert \vert f_n - f \rvert \rvert_\infty \to 0 $?

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194354/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-p-infty) provides a suitable counterexample if we omit the condition that $\lvert f_n(x) \rvert \le \lvert f(x) \rvert $ a.e.

In the above link $f_n \to 0$ a.e. but always a set of positive measure where the bounding fails. So I am trying to find a potential counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Define $f: (0,1] \to \mathbb R$ by $f(x) = \frac 1 x$ for $x \in (0,1]$, and let $f_n(x) = \min(n,f(x))$ for any $x \in (0,1]$. Then $\lvert f_n(x) \rvert \le \lvert f(x)\rvert$ for all $x$ and $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for all $x \in(0,1]$, but $f_n \not \to f$ in $L^\infty$.

Comment: To add to this: even if $f(x)$ is bounded the answer is still no. Consider $f_n(x) = \frac 2 \pi \arctan(x)$ for $x \in [-1,1]$. Then $\lvert f_n(x)\rvert \le 1$ and $f_n$ converges pointwise to the signum function, but the convergence is not uniform because each $f_n$ is continuous but the limit is discontinuous.